# pgsql.so is not loaded in PHP

Tags: php, apache, php-extension

I've been tasked to create a PHP app which accesses an existing PostgreSQL database. This is my first time working with Postgre, not to mention the PHP has already been installed in the Linux box on which the app is supposed to run. I have no experience setting up this stuff, I just code.

My question is that I can't seem to get the Postgre extension working in PHP. I checked the php.ini file, there were no "extension=..." lines. So I added "extension=pgsql.so". I then checked the "extension_dir" and found that there were only 2 files in there (ldap.so, phpcups.so), I added a pgsql.so file taken from another Linux box. I restarted httpd. And it does not work. I couldn't find any "pgsql" or "postgre" in phpinfo().

Forgive my noobness. I know too little Linux. I would really appreciate it if you can point me to the right direction.

---

I used the suggestion given by number5:

Dude, I'm on RedHat. I used the "yum" version of the command you gave, and I got this:

[root@perseus ~]# yum install php-pgsql
Loading "installonlyn" plugin
Setting up Install Process
Setting up repositories
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5&arch=x86_64&repo=extras error was
[Errno 4] IOError: 
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: extras

---

UNFORTUNATELY, the Linux server I'm using is NOT connected to the Internet. Any other way to install?

Comment: That looks like a question for ServerFault.

Comment: hope you already solved your problem. If not, you can download the required rpms and install using rpm command.

wget http://mirrors.gigenet.com/centos/5.4/os/x86_64/CentOS/php-pdo-5.1.6-23.2.el5_3.x86_64.rpm
wget http://mirrors.gigenet.com/centos/5.4/os/x86_64/CentOS/php-pgsql-5.1.6-23.2.el5_3.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh *.rpm

if it tells you that some deps are missing, you can find it here http://mirrors.gigenet.com/centos/5.4/os/x86_64/CentOS/

the download link is assuming that your CentOS is 5.4 x86_64

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on which Linux distro you are using.

If you are using Ubuntu/Debian, you need to:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

Fedora/CentOS

```
yum install php-pgsql
```

usually you can find out which distro you are on by:

```
ls /etc/*-release
```

Comment: Dude I added some comments above

Answer (score 3):

On CentOS extensions create separate *.ini file one per each php extension in /etc/php.d

So, don't alter main *.ini file, but create /etc/php.d/pgsql.ini and add there a line

```
extension=pgsql.so
```

Then you will need to restart Apache using

```
service httpd restart
```

But the best automated way is to just type

```
yum install php-pgsql
```

In your case that didn't work because of some problems in yum configuration. Go to /etc/yum-repos.d
Type

```
nano /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

Scroll down to [extras] section and ensure it is like this:

```
#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
priority=1
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
=extras
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
```

Correct it if needed, save file (Ctrl-X) and do the following:

```
yum clean all
yum upgrade
```

Afterwards try to repeat

```
yum install php-pgsql
```

Comment: it says:

Config Error: File contains parsing errors: file://///etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
        [line 41]: '=extras\n'

Comment: Who says? What's your CentOS version? May be, you should remove "priority" string?

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the .so file you've copied from the other machine (though it might work, there's no need to take the risk)
- Use the distribution's package manager to install the php_pgsql/php5_pqsql module
- Restart the apache and try again. Maybe the module has been added to an .ini file automagically
- If not, run `<?php echo 'ini: ', get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');` to see which php.ini you have to edit
- edit this ini file
- restart the apache

Answer (score -1):

My operation system Linux mint kde and there was same issue

> pg_connect()

You must install if you are use php5.6

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-pgsql
```

After you must change extention name in "php.ini" file.

```
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

'dll' to 'so'

For example

```
extension=php_pgsql.so
```

Comment: This seems like a different issue. For a start, the OP already had that config line exactly as written.